# Laravel WhereHas only the latest record on the HasMany Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have **Items** table that has relation to **Histories** table.

I want to get count of **items** that has only latest **history.status**

I still can't get the exact same count result because its always count all of the histories not the latest one

Here is my code:

**create_items_table.php**

```
Schema::create('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('code');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->longText('description')->nullable();
        $table->longText('picture')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**create_histories_table.php**

```
$table->foreignId('item_id')->constrained();
$table->string('status')->nullable();
$table->longText('description')->nullable();
$table->dateTime('date')->nullable();
```

model of **Item.php**

```
public function histories(){
        return $this->hasMany(History::class);
    }
public function latestHistory(){
        return $this->hasOne(History::class)->latest();
    }
```

model of **History.php**

```
public function item()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Item::class);
}
```

**MyController.php**

```
 $items_status['good'] = Item::with('latestHistory')->whereHas('latestHistory', function ($q) {
            $q->where('status', 'good');
        })->count();

 $items_status['broken'] = Item::with('latestHistory')->whereHas('latestHistory', function ($q) {
            $q->where('status', 'broken');
        })->count();

dd($items_status);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i guess you mean [latestOfMany()](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-of-many) ?

```php
//Item.php
public function latestHistory() {
        return $this->hasOne(History::class)->latestOfMany();
    }
```

---

> Also do you have any solution for count the items that doesn't have
> history?
> [Check docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence) for `doesntHave`

```php
$items_status['no_history'] = Item::doesntHave('history')->count();
```

Comment: Also do you have any solution for count the items that doesn't have history?